# Connect to oracle 9i database in c# from remote desktop

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle

How can I get data from oracle 9i database in c# from remote desktop in asp.net application?

The asp.net application will be deployed on one server and Oracle Database on another.

How can I communicate both servers to get data from Oracle Database.

**I tried this**

```
string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=StaticIPAddressOfOracelServers)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=serviceName)));User Id=Administrator;Password=pass;";
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
conn.Open();
```

and I get this exception:

> ORA-03111: Break received on communication channel

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you resolved it somehow in mean time ?

Comment: after some struggle i leave it ... I done my work in another way.

Answer (score 1):

ODP.NET, Managed Driver supports connecting to Oracle DB server 10.2 or higher. It does not support 9i as stated in [this post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2528641).